# js make all the url parameter's value have an " "

Tags: javascript, iframe, parameters, src

I have an iframe which includes src like this:

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="/jsp/transfer/a.jsp?isChange=true&bizId="+bizId></iframe>
```

bizId is a number. For example:

```
src = "/jsp/transfer/a.jsp?isChange=true&bizId=10"
```

I notice that Javascript will make put bizId's value in quotes: "10", "null", etc. I want to get the actual numeric value, not a string. Why is it represented as a string? What should I do?

Comment: bizId is Ok, i just want to know why I get the value have " ".

Comment: you can't alter elements via javascript just by adding variables wherever you please

Comment: @diligent No, to solve your problem we need to know when are you generating that bizId. Is it a Javascript variable? Is it server-side variable? Is it generated on click of the button (some javascript event) or on rendering your page (server-side event)?

Comment: @Max yes, bizId are generated from the server-side, I test it, it's all right. It will be return a number, then i made it as parameter to the iframe's url. and I'll get it on another jsp page I called it jsp B, then I passed bizId back to server-side. But on jsp B,when I obtain bizid i found every value have a ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem right (especially your last comment), you need to do this:

`<iframe id="frame1" src="/jsp/transfer/a.jsp?isChange=true&bizId=<%=bizId>"></iframe>`

Explanation:

`<%= variable >` - is a JSP syntax for inserting variables from JSP context into rendered HTML. This code (`<%= variable >`) will be replaced fully by contents of `variable`.

**Added:** (in response to comment)

If you need to put some variable into JavaScript file which is included from your original JSP file, you wont be able to use `<%= variable >` syntax in it. However, here is what you can do:

**[yourjsp.jsp]**

```
<script>
var bizId = <%=bizId>;
</script>
...
<script src="yourjavascript.js"></script>
```

**[yourjavascript.js]**

```
function someMethod() {
    alert(bizId); 
}
```

Basically, JSP code will be replaced, and you will define a global javascript variable called `bizId` containing the value of server-side `bizId`. Then, any other javascript code can use that variable.

Comment: I use a separate js file contains all the javascript and my jsp page include the js file. in that case , can I use <%= variable > in my js file ?

Comment: @diligent No you can't. Your JS file is not a JSP, so it will not be replaced with all this variables. I've edited my response on what to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

in JS :

```
window.frames["myIframe"].src = "/jsp/transfer/a.jsp?isChange=true&bizId="+bizId;
```

you Can't add to the src something like `+param`.

option 1 ) via server side

option 2) via Js - change the SRC.

### edit

```
<iframe name="myIframe" id="frame1" src=""></iframe>


in the bottom of the page : 

<script type="text/javascript">

var bizId=444;

window.onload = function() {  
   window.frames["myIframe"].src = "/jsp/transfer/a.jsp?isChange=true&bizId="+bizId;
};  

</script>
```

Comment: thanks Royi, how can I change the SRC via Js. Ps, I add src like +param everywhere in my code, how should I do ,what's your suggestion?